Cover circle with minimum rectangles
Following is something I have met when implementing nav-mesh using rectangles in a computer game.
Assume we have a circle and we want to have it covered by a set of rectangles. We want the total area of rectangles to be as small as possible, while covering the whole circle. I can solve this for three rectangles, because intuition tells me the solution needs to be symmetrical, therefore the point will lie on a diagonal:

The diagonal of the red square will be $ \frac {\sqrt {2}}{2} - \frac {1} {2} $, and its side will be $ \frac {1}{2} - \frac {1} {2 \sqrt {2}} $
Now I would like to solve the same problem for five rectangles. When we consider just one quadrant, the solution will most likely look like this:

Now what is the optimum size of the red and dark-green squares, so that the area covered by green rectangles is minimal?
By running numerical optimization my result was:

red square: 0.2163
dark green square: 0.1281

This is good enough for my application, but I am curious - how would I derive the optimum size analytically and what would it be?

It's not a nice expression. You can set up an exact equation using the fact that each leg of the red L-shape is a rectangle with the same ratio as the coordinates of the point on the circle. That leads to an equation $\cos(x) \sin(x) - \cos^2(x) - \sin(x) + \sin^2(x) = 0$ where the point on the circle is $(0.5\cos(x),0.5\sin(x))$. Wolfram Alpha can give an exact solution, but as it involves a cubic or quartic equation, it is horrible. ($x=0.96756424023956075288$)

Thanks. What I do not understand is how is this x related to my red or green box size?

$(0.5\cos(x), 0.5\sin(x)) = (0.2836535, 0.4117532)$ is the higher of the two points on the circle, so the red square is of size $0.5-0.2836535=0.2163465$ and the green is then $0.2163465 -(0.5-0.4117532)=0.1280996$.

Assume you have $2n-1$ rectangles. Can I try to phrase your question as: Let $0=\phi_0<\phi_1<\dots<\phi_n<\pi/2$. Then find the minimum of $\sum_{i=1}^n (\sin(\phi_i)-\sin(\phi_{i-1}))\cos(\phi_{i-1})$?

@JetfiRex Perhaps you want to write this as an answer instead, as it basically answers this question (albeit in a more general form)?

@Suma Oh, I just want to phrase it in a more formal way, but I still can't solve this problem... (And I don't believe it has a good-looking solution, though)
